# How to create posters using LaTeX

Tags: document-classes, big-list, posters

I want to create posters for my poster presentation on a conference. What tools or LaTeX classes are available for preparing posters ?

Comment: I have made several conference posters using LaTeX, but I have stopped. If you can, you should absolutely try to use more visual software. Even PowerPoint is better than LaTeX. LaTeX isn't made for designing posters (or presentations) and it shows.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this comment. (Also, I do not think this qualifies as an answer to the author's question.) LaTeX can and has been harnessed to efficiently produce excellent posters of the highest quality and with minimum formatting hassles.

Comment: Well, naturally I expected some disagreement here. :-) However, I stand by my statement that LaTeX is not (and not meant to be) very useful for this task. For presentations it is even more obvious, due to the limitations of PDF itself.

Comment: PDF has more features for presentations than you might think. :-) It supports page/slide transitions (though personally I *hated* them back in my PowerPoint days), and you can even add animations e.g. with the beamer package. Having said that, I believe transitions and animations should be used sparingly (if at all!) as they can be very distracting. (Unless you are preparing a marketing/sales presentation, then the bells and whistles are certainly desirable...)

Comment: I have seen a lot of really good presentations and animations really help sometimes, when the phenomenon you are describing is something moving. 

Let's just say that most of the really good presentations I have seen on conferences would be close to impossible to typeset in LaTeX in any reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Actually I have to agree wholeheartedly with this statement; as I’ve said elsewhere, though I use LaTeX for everything else, I strongly feel that presentations (and yes, to an extend posters) are better made in other software. And I’m surprised since my answers didn’t attrackt this much disagreement.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: I am at a conference now and I still stand by this answer. It is even more true for presentations, though.

Comment: This is my first down vote. There are definitely tasks for which TeX is ill suited or probably not the best tool. I can think of at least two examples. One is writing Unix man pages and the second one is typing Music (yes it is possible with TeX but LilyPond is just much more suitable and is developed by people who dropped music TeX). However, TeX is fantastic tool for creating posters and particularly presentations. You have to move beyond Beamer and look at the things like Powerdot and little helper programs like ImPress http://typophile.com/node/43702.

Comment: @Ben I gave you a wrong link for Impressive. This is the correct link http://impressive.sourceforge.net/. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'd recommend the `beamerposter` package. It seamingly integrates with the `beamer` class, thereby opening the box of goodies that's called `tikz` and making available the standard `beamer` styles. I've made a [presentation](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html) available about making `beamer` presentations and posters with the `beamerposter` package. Links are provided in the presentation and if you use TeXLive then you may find more information about the package by executing the command `texdoc beamerposter` from the command line.

Comment: Let me add one small but perhaps important reason for using LaTeX for a poster: if everything else (paper, presentation, ...) is written in LaTeX, obviously, "integrating existing contents" *(cough)* is much easier if your target format is LaTeX than if it is anything else. For instance, placing tables and plots, reformatted to the dimensions of a poster column *and* using the same font (and the same font size) as the poster, went very quickly for my most recent poster -- not to mention textual contents with occasional LaTeX commands. ...

Comment: Other software has "Import PDF" for sure, but achieving this kind of consistency (for which I personally care a lot) will be a very tough job.

Comment: @ those who recommend not using latex, what would you recommend using in that case? The only suggestion I saw was "even powerpoint" which suggests there is better out there...?

Comment: I guess no solution is ideal... A commercial software like InDesign is an alternative, but I haven't used it myself. I usually use Inkscape, but it's buggy sometimes, has few typographic options, and it's tedious to include math. A "perfect" poster could be crafted by a combination of LaTeX and Inkscape (either embedding Inkscape graphics in LaTeX or importing LaTeX text/formulas into Inkscape)

Comment: This tutorial is helpful and contains examples:
https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Posters

Answer (score 148):

The [`beamerposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter) package is quite nice.

Examples:

[image] [image]

Comment: In particular, it integrates extremely well with TikZ (after all, it written by the same person). I find that understanding beamer theme definitions is essential to getting the desired output, however.

Comment: The beamer-poster package is great. See http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php for some examples.

Comment: Here is an example of a custom theme definition I created while in grad. school that you might be able to use as a starting point: http://svn.sultanik.com/drexelcsposter/

Comment: @mbq: Could you perhaps add a really basic example of a poster built with `beamerposter`? Just a kind of "hello world", so that users can see what it's like right here without having to go to external sites.

Comment: Slight correction to the comment from a few years ago: beamer and tikz were written by the same person, but beamerposter was not.

Answer (score 95):

Elena Botoeva has written a new package for creating posters with TikZ, called [fancytikzposter](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Eebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html). There are already five templates with different node shapes and colors.

[Sample](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Eebotoeva/tikz/fancytikzposter.pdf):

[image: Sample posters]

Note that as [indicated by the author](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Eebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html),

> NOTE that we joined our efforts with the tikzposter team, which resulted in an improved version 2.0 of the tikzposter class that you can find in http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter. This class combines both good structure and nice layouts. The official webpage of our project is https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/wiki/ (under construction).
>
> I am not going to maintain this style.

See the [tikzposter answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164082/73420).

Comment: This is not maintained anymore. Instead, a [new version](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter) is available.

Comment: (If you look hard enough, you will see the new version has been added as a separate answer.)

Answer (score 65):

[`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/) is a LaTeX class designed for posters.

Look at the example file included in the class' zip file and you will probably find your way.

A few quick tips :

- You can position boxes by giving them names with `name=abc` and positioning other boxes using `below=abc`
- You can set the total number of columns in the document by giving "columns=X" parameter in the `\begin{poster}` parameters.

EDIT - one of the example posters:

[image: baposter example]

Comment: Could you perhaps add a really basic example of a poster built with `baposter`? Just a kind of "hello world", so that users can see what it's like right here without having to go to external sites.

Comment: Baposter has nice templates. The one whose image I have added to this post saved me three years ago. It was my first encounter with TeX, and made a nice poster.

Comment: I just found that baposter's last update was few months after I used it for the first time (2011), and the package for dowmload is packaged, at least for me. I withdraw my upvote for this project.

Comment: @doncherry I made a basic baposter template a while back... https://gjabel.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/basic-hello-world-baposter-poster/

Answer (score 64):

The already mentioned [`fancytikzposter`](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html) by Elena Botoeva now merged with *`tikzposter`* to form `tikzposter` 2.0 ([Bitbucket wiki](https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/wiki/Home), [CTAN resource](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter)) which is a great solution to build beautiful posters:

[image: tikzposter preview]

Comment: I've seen there is also a tikzcode, http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzcodeblocks/tikzcodeblocks-documentation.pdf . What does it add to tikzposter or what is the difference? Unfortunately the manual is not in English.

Comment: Current version is [2.0](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter), dated 2014. Many open [bugs](https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/issues) and does not seem maintained any more.

Answer (score 32):

Previously, I wasted a lot of time trying to get sufficiently large paper sizes, sufficiently large fonts, etc. And even when I was successful, I had difficulties with PDF previewers that e.g. waste ridiculous amounts of memory if you open an A0 document. Finally I realised that I can simply **create my poster in A4 size**. Then you just ask that it's printed in A0 size (a single click in Adobe Reader printing dialog; in most cases, even your local university press *can* do it). You can easily preview your poster by simply printing it on an A4 printer.

I usually use 8pt fonts (`\footnotesize`) in my A4 posters. It translates to 32pt fonts when scaled to A0, which seems to be a suitable size for a typical conference poster. Nowadays I'm simply using the `article` class and settings such as

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\raggedright
```

You can use the `textpos` package to place "text boxes" using absolute coordinates. Other useful packages include `color`, `titlesec`, `enumitem`, and `psnfss`.

For very large fonts (e.g. poster title), you can use something like `\fontsize{26}{30}\selectfont` – alternatively, you can use the `\scalebox` command. For layout tweaks: `\hspace`, `\vspace`, `\makebox`, `\parbox`, `\raisebox`. For drawing lines and boxes: `\rule`.

Comment: I have never had any problems opening A0 document.  I recommend creating the poster in its true size, since that will enable commands like `\vspace{1cm}` to do what's expected.

Comment: Another reason for creating your poster in its original size is that if you use a font with optical scaling, then you will get the correct weight.  (Large fonts != small fonts scaled up).  See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/selecting-optical-size) for example.

Answer (score 28):

I have some advice on this topic elsewhere, which includes pointers to other resources: [Using LaTeX to produce conference posters](http://nxg.me.uk/docs/posters/)

Myself, I think that the most useful package for a task like this is the [`textpos` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) (disclaimer: I wrote that, as a spinoff from the task of laying out posters).

Comment: I've created several conference posters with the a0-poster class you link to, in combination with your textpos package (so thanks!), and been very happy with the results.

Comment: +1 - ditto to Michael Underwood's comment -  thanks. The only additional feature I could want from texpos is for text that is too long to fit in for one block to automatically 'column-break' into an assigned next block. Not really possible in LaTeX though, I suspect...

Comment: @Chris: check out [flowfram](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/flowfram.html)

Answer (score 24):

In the site [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/conference-posters) there are three downloadable  Conference Posters templates: baposter Portrait Poster, Dreuw & Deselaer's Poster and Jacobs Landscape Poster.

Example: [Jacobs Landscape Poster](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster)

> Description:
>
> This poster template features a clean sectioned look suitable for
>   presenting research at a conference. Important information is
>   highlighted with colored boxes and each section within the poster is
>   clearly separated from the others. The layout of the template contains
>   four columns but this can be changed to accommodate varying amounts of
>   information or figures. Examples of a table, figure, equation, list
>   and bibliography are present in the template to provide a starting
>   point for any requirement you may have for your own poster.
>
> Original Author:
>
> This template was originally created by the Computational Physics and
>   Biophysics Group, Jacobs University and was then modified by Nathaniel
>   Johnston. Finally, it has been extensively modified for this website.

uses

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter}
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

[`a0poster`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/a0poster) and [`sciposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sciposter) are two document classes that are designed to help you make posters. `a0poster` worked better for me.

Comment: I used a0poster myself for my physics thesis and I loved it. The output was stunning and it was very simple to use. There's a wonderful template and excellent example on Andreas Jung's blog: http://andreas.welcomes-you.com/projects/a0poster/

Comment: Nearly all my posters [1] were done with the \usepackage{sciposter} which I wholeheartedly recommend. If you're interested in the source, just send me an email. [1]: http://www.ana.unibe.ch/~haberthuer/posters

Comment: @Habi Dead link.

Comment: @TommiBrander I cannot edit the comment, so you'll find the posters here: http://wiki.davidhaberthuer.ch/posters

Answer (score 20):

There is also the `umbcposter` package (similar to `baposter`). You can download it from:
[math.umbc.edu/~rouben/umbcposter](http://math.umbc.edu/~rouben/umbcposter)

The site also provides a good on-line users' guide, as well as a sample poster to get started and a gallery of posters that have used the package.

Here is part of the sample poster provided:

```
% sample.tex % A sample UMBCposter.% Rouben Rostamian, February 2010

\documentclass[paper=a4paper,landscape,dvipsnames]{umbcposter}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \LARGE\sc This is the title \\[0.6ex]
    \Large\sl Rouben Rostamian\\
    \Large UMBC
\end{tabular}
}
\posterinit{
%grid,
background style = {left color = Apricot, right color = white},
title = {\mytitle},
right logo,       % use default
left logo,        % use default
box/border style, % use default
box/header style, % use default
box/body style = {bottom color=blue!10, top color=red!5},
box/all rounded,
}
\boxit{col = 0, at top, name=box1}{Title of Box 1}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item col = 0
    \item at top
    \item name = box1
\end{itemize}
}
\boxit{col = 0, below of=box1, name=box2}{Title of Box 2}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item col = 0
    \item below of = box1
    \item name = box2
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Link may have moved to https://userpages.umbc.edu/~rostamia/umbcposter/

Answer (score 16):

Since version 4.10, [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) offers a `poster` library which combines its already known capabilities for colorful boxes creation with `baposter` positioning system.

The starting point for boxes distribution over the poster is a typical matrix (row and columns) but boxes placement or size are not restricted to the scheme. 
Boxes length can be automatically computed with other boxes as reference. And boxes can be broken and its content flow between fragments.

Following code shows a little example. You can find a more detailed example in [tcolorbox-example-poster](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox-example-poster.pdf) tutorial or 
in [Thomas F. Sturm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378438/1952) answer to [Creating this poster layout using minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375698/creating-this-poster-layout-using-minipages/378438#378438)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
    coverage = {
        spread,
        interior style = {top color = white, bottom color = brown!80!black},
    },
    poster = {
%       showframe, 
        columns=3, rows=5},
    boxes = {
        colframe=brown!80!black,
        colback=brown!50,
    },
    fontsize = 12pt,        
]

\posterbox{name=title, column=1, span=3, below=top}{
{\Large This is a very nice poster made with \texttt{tcolorbox}}\\tex.stackexchange.com}

\posterbox[adjusted title=Introduction]{name=intro, column=1, span=2, below = title}{\lipsum[2]}

\posterbox{name=logo, column*=3, span=.5, above=bottom}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[yellow] circle (1cm);
\fill[red] (45:.5cm) circle (1mm) (135:.5cm) circle (1mm);
\draw[red, line width=1mm] (215:5mm) arc (215:325:5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\posterbox[adjusted title=Conclusions]{name=conc, column=2, span=2, above = logo}{\lipsum[2]}


\posterbox[adjusted title=Acknowledgments]{name=ack, span = 2.5, column = 1, between = conc and bottom}{\Huge  Thank you to Thomas F. Sturm}

\posterbox[adjusted title=Description, colback=white]{name=desc, sequence = 1 between intro and ack then 2 between intro and conc then 3 between title and conc}{\lipsum[1-4]}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have not seen any support for big font sizes, which seem mandatory when creating big (A0, e.g.) posters.

Comment: In my experience, this is by far the best poster package I have used, having formerly used `baposter` and experimented unsuccessfully with `beamerposter`. You can use the `fontsize` package to implement large font sizes very easily.

Answer (score 9):

I recently dicovered [`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/). It is based on pgf so tikz related things will work fine. The macros are fairly easy to understand and Brain (the author) shows quite a lot of examples.

All I can say that I recently won the poster price at a conference with a baposter designed poster.

Comment: That's impressive, well done! Is your poster available on line somewhere?

Comment: Redundant with existing answer about the same class, see above.

Answer (score 8):

The TeX FAQ has an entry [Creating posters with LaTeX](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-poster). I also have a tutorial [Creating Technical Posters with LaTeX](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/posters/) as well as a [tutorial on creating LaTeX posters with a GUI](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/manual/postertutorial.html). My `flowfram` package has already been mentioned in a comment. It has an example poster in the [samples directory](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram/samples/).

Answer (score 8):

Faced with the task to provide a poster **template** for our institute I just created a small [github repository](https://github.com/mamueller/Markus-LaTeX-poster-guide/blob/master/README.md)  with complete self-explanatory examples for:

1. [beamerposter](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamerposter?lang=en) with columns
2. beamerposter with package textpos (recommended by the beameruserguide)
3. beamerposter [tcolorboxes](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) (using its poster library)
4. a [baposter.cls](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster) fork

In particular I discuss the problem of vertical alignment which can be a bit unnerving in some approaches. 
Given the existence of a predefined beamer style file.
I found the tacolorboxes approach to be the most flexible, but in the example posters I also discuss the alternatives in more depth.