# Really large poster in a0poster or other package

Tags: posters

I am designing a poster for a conference (first one in many years). I am using a0poster, but the poster allows for two panels, one of which is 4 feet square, the other 4 feet by 2 feet, with a hinge between.

a0poster seems to have a maximum size of 33" by 46".  I could make two posters, one a0 and one smaller, but is there a way to make it in one poster?

Comment: See also [How to create posters using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Beamerposter](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter) can handle custom page sizes, at least. Not sure about other classes, but since I already was using beamer for presentations, beamerposter was an easy transition.

Example (72" wide, 48" high):

[image]

important bit (lengths in cm by default, may be able to change to more comfortable units):

```
\usepackage[size=custom,width=182.88,height=121.92,scale=3]{beamerposter} % e.g. for custom size poster
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer} % beamer 3.10: do NOT use option hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false} !
\mode<presentation> {  %% check http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php for examples
  \usetheme{Berlin}    %% you should define your own theme e.g. for big headlines using your own logos 
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\boldmath
\usepackage[size=custom,width=182.88,height=121.92,scale=3]{beamerposter} % e.g. for custom size poster
\title[Giant Posters]{Making Giant Posters with \LaTeX}
\author[One \& Two]{First One and Second Two}
\institute[Big U]{Some Department, Big University}
\date{Jul. 27th, 2011}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \leavevmode

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \begin{columns}[T]
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.7\paperwidth}
        \vskip8ex
        \raggedleft
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}     
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.25\paperwidth}
        \vskip8ex
        \begin{center}
          Logo goes here.
        \end{center}
        \vskip2ex
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vskip2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4ex,leftskip=1em,rightskip=1em]{author in head/foot}%
    \texttt{http://www.bigu.edu/}
    \hfill
    \texttt{(one,two)@bigu.edu}
    \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{columns}[t]
      \begin{column}{0.32\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
          \centering
          {\tiny tiny}\par
          {\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
          {\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
          {\normalsize normalsize}\par
          {\large large}\par
          {\Large Large}\par
          {\LARGE LARGE}\par
          {\veryHuge veryHuge}\par
          {\VeryHuge VeryHuge}\par
          {\VERYHuge VERYHuge}\par
        \end{block}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{\large Other Things}
          Other things go here.
        \end{block}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I already used that basic poster in a class I ran earlier this year, so I just adjusted the size and stripped out the identifying information.