# Which documentclass provides typesetting a very large poster?

Tags: document-classes, posters

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Really large poster in a0poster or other package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24264/really-large-poster-in-a0poster-or-other-package)
>   [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex)

I want to create a poster (.PDF file) with these dimensions:

- Width: 3 meters
- Height: 1 meter

Inside I would like to put

- 1 raster file
- 1 EPS
- many typeset

Is it possible to create by LaTeX? If yes, can someone suggest some documentclass that supports this big format?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24264/really-large-poster-in-a0poster-or-other-package answer your question?

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex might be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `sciposter` document class.  This supports posters of ISO A3
size and larger (ISO A0 is the default size).  Here's the link:

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sciposter/

Alternatively, try the `baposter` package, which allows you to specify all page sizes using the `paperwidth=` and `paperheight=` class options.  Here's the link:

http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/