# Publicity Poster

Tags: posters, flyers

I am looking for a good poster class for latex. Googling gave only conference posters. This is for a program.

Is there any specific classes for it. Or I need to stick to conference poster

Comment: Have a look at [a0poster](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/a0poster) and [beamerposter](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter). On a lower level there is [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos).

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex) would help you, it seems to pretty much cover yours.

Comment: If you've used the `beamer` class before then I'd also recommend the `[beamerposter](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php) package.

Comment: Are you really sure that TeX is the best tool for this job? I used to make posters and presentations with LaTeX, but now I have realized that there are much better tools for this job (unlike typesetting documents).

Comment: @Ben It seems GIMP fits well that LaTeX for me :)

Comment: another tikz based poster package is `umbcposter` www.math.umbc.edu/~rouben/umbcposter/

Answer (score 7):

If the publicity poster is more of a flyer (around A4 size), then regular beamer will work fine. If it's really poster-sized (around A0), then beamerposter. And yes, depending on how much control you want in where things go, you might be better off with illustration software instead. However, here's what I've used for short course publicity in the past:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default} % no need for borders, sidebars, etc.
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % no need for navigation symbols

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{CAE Short Courses for Graduate and REU Students}
% [fragile] since I have a \verb for the email address. Could be removed if you use
% \texttt{} instead.

\begin{columns}[t] % top-aligned columns

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
Basic information
\begin{itemize}
\item Selected topics relevant to research and publication
\item Each course is independent of the others: sign up for one, two, or all
\item Tuesdays and Thursdays, 6:00--9:00 pm
\item 4 meetings (2 weeks) per course
\item No registration fee
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
Courses and starting dates
\begin{itemize}
\item \bfseries{Introduction to Linux and UNIX: January 25}
\item \bfseries{Introduction to MATLAB: February 8}
\item \bfseries{Introduction to \LaTeX{}: February 22}
\end{itemize}
Other courses may be offered, depending on interest and availability.
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\begin{center}
To register, or for more information, email Mike Renfro \verb|<renfro@tntech.edu>|
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```