# change title font and text font for preparing IEEE poster

Tags: fontsize, paper-size, posters, ieee-style

I had prepared a paper for an IEEE Conf. Now, it's required to prepare a poster for presenting my work.

Some of guidelines of preparing poster are as follow:

1. Poster Space: Plan on using an area that consists of two side-by-side bulletin boards,
   each 1.2 m tall x 2.4 m wide (4 × 8ft).

2.The title of your paper should appear in block letters, which are at least 10 cm high (4
in). The remaining text should be at least 5 cm high (2 in) to be easily legible to viewers
who are standing as far as 2 meters away. Each graph or chart should be at least 27 × 21
cm (11 × 8.5 in) with text that is also readable from 2 meters away.Provide an
Introduction or Outline, and Summary or Conclusion.

How can I change my paper size from a4 to guideline1?
I added the following line

`\special{papersize=120cm,240cm}`

to change my paper size.

How can I change title and text font size?

this is my title :

`\title{\LARGE My Title}`

and how can I change its font size?

Comment: Also have a look at the `beamerposter` package. You can find a lot of examples [on this page](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php). Warning, a little bit of pain required to customize the headline :) Start reading the theme files first.

Comment: there are quite a few latex poster packages which may be of use you; see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex/7309#7309

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make titles and text really big, consider using the fix-cm package:

```
\usepackage{fix-cm}
```

Then, when you want to specify the text size you can write:

```
   \title{{\fontsize{200}{240}\selectfont Your text here}}
```

Work on the two numbers to adjust the size.

Comment: I tried {\fontsize{2000}{2400}\selectfont 
\title{ title goese here}
} but it didn't work out :( .

Comment: You need to nest in the other way around:                               \title{{\fontsize{200}{240}\selectfont Your text here}}

Comment: Thanks Edo. But it's difficult to change text font size in this way because I need to exclude fig. captions and ... separately. Can you suggest another solution?

Comment: Another problem is that it did n't work out with abstract and keywords sections