# what is the best package for making a math poster?

Tags: packages, posters, beamerposter, sciposter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex)

I am going to make a poster. I find that there are several possibilities: e.g.,  beamerposter, a0poster, baposter. Does anyone know which is the best one to make a math poster? Thanks a lot!

Comment: (since it's a math poster) What's the metric defined on the space of math poster packages?

Comment: have a look at [how-to-create-posters-using-latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex)

Comment: @ percusse, sorry, I have no idea. :-(

Comment: can we close as a duplicate then?