# Could TeX.SE put on a showcase of scientific posters?

Tags: big-list, posters

Could the people of the TeX.SE put on a showcase of scientific posters made with (La)TeX? I have seen other showcases on here, [this collection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/52745#52745) for example. However, with a large number of people using (La)Tex for scientific publications (which often end up as posters), I think it would be valuable for such a thing to exist.

Comment: This question becomes a subset of the existing question.

Comment: I would say the question itself should be moved to meta.tex.SE

Comment: If you want this question to be such a collection, it seems better to make it a community wiki and tag it big-list.

Comment: I'm not really that clued up on the structure of the forum but the other collection I referred to is 'community wiki'.

Comment: I made it to CW since it's a "list of" question and intended as a community effort.

Comment: Check on this site http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/conference-posters it has templates for sientific poster. I think that it is satisfactory.

Comment: As LaTeX is mostly used for technical / scientific purpose, the asnwers of [How to create posters using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex) are probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @Xavier The purpose of this list was/is to exhibit some great examples of scientific posters in terms of layout and style, not the generic 'how to create a poster'.

Comment: I don't have posters but I do have notes that I could post links to as examples.

Comment: I'm not sure what good answers here might look like. Most scientific posters are not that exciting to look at, and judging them requires expertise on the subject at hand. Moreover, often the _content_ can't be banded about freely.

Comment: Related or Possible Duplicate [How to create posters using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341/15717)