# Please can someone explain to me how I can add a class!

Tags: installing, mactex, mac

I am a non-technical user. I use LaTeX to type up stuff and that's it. What I want to do is make posters like from this website. http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/

I think this gives me a new "class". How can I make it so that when I open TeXShop I can just type in the document class and then make my poster? I am pulling out my hair trying to find how to install this "class"!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: have you seen [How to create posters using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341)

Comment: just extract/unzip the [baposter.tar.bz2](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter.tar.bz2) and go to the -> `examples` ->EECS2011 folder and open `poster.tex` with TeXshop and typeset. it has `baposter.cls` file and also guide to baposter. keep the `.cls` file in the folder where you want to generate the .pdf instead of installing permanently, if you are a non-technical user.

Comment: This is mainly a duplicate of [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10256/2693).