# Posters for a project

Tags: posters

I am look for advice on posters in LaTeX. I was wondering whether could refer me to someone that has good templates?

Comment: Btw, read this: [How to create posters using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex).

Comment: As it stands, this is not a great fit for a 'Q&A' site: it is likely to be closed as 'not a real question' as it's very broad. Can you edit it to make it more specific, for example to focus on some concrete aspect of the process.

Comment: Hi! This question is way too broad. Please try to use some of the packages in the page linked by @m0nhawk, and if you have any specific issues using them, ask about these issues ;)

Answer (score 1):

That sound a bit of broad question. But I'll try to share what I've done with posters in LaTeX. And what I've learned from it.

Before the start, the type of poster is the important. From my experience I can divide posters into two types:

- advertisement: any poster which presenting something in a creative manner;
- informational: a nicely partitioned information.

Creating posters of the first type can be painful (I recommend to use some more suitable software, like [QuarkXPress](http://www.quark.com/), [Adobe InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign/) or [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator/)).

Posters of the second type is much popular with LaTeX in academic circles. Let's take a look into the search on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/search?phrase=poster) for `poster` keyword:

> The search found 9 of 9 hits in 8ms.

First one is the topic of all packages that typesets posters. I won't stop (maybe later) on the each package, just give a broad information about typesetting (almost all classic typesetting rules is applied) posters:

- Posters going to be viewed from almost any distance: the title and partitioning should be recognisable from several centimetres to several meters.
- Title needs to be catchy and convey what the poster about. Under the title the author list should be presented.
- Do not include abstract. It useless. Usually people asked to *submit* the abstract, not for abstract to be *presented* on poster.
- Use at least 3 columns (for `A2` poster). Or more for larger sizes (`A1` and `A0`). I suggest to leave only title the only non-column elements. The boxes should be only 40-80 characters wide.
- Use boxes, colours and rules to subdivide poster into semantics parts.
- Use **only** vector graphics: `.eps`, `.svg`, vector graphics packages: `tikz`, `pstricks`. As mentioned, it going to be viewed from small distance and raster graphics would look really bad. But if you need them: export (not resave) as `.png` or `.tiff` with large density (300 dpi for printing is enough, usually it's 96 dpi).

Comment: Can you please add links to examples (preferably source + something ready-to-view)?

Comment: @moose: I'm currently working on them.