# Adding a background image with tikz poster

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

When using the `tikzposter` package, is it possible to add a background image?

I currently have a colour gradient, and would preferably like to keep this intact, and superpose the image on top of that.

The current document looks somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

%% colors
% title
\definecolor{backgroundcolortop}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{backgroundcolormiddle}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{backgroundcolorbottom}{RGB}{91,195,240}

\title{Ttile}
\author{{\LARGE Authors}\\{\normalsize email}}
\institute{{\Large Institute}}

\begin{document}
\titleblock[seperated=false, embedded=true]
%...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, but *complete* version of your document, showing the relevant settings; in particular, we need to see the settings for the current colour gradient you mentioned.

Comment: I think this is not provided out of the box in the current version. Please be patient, the guys from this class and two other people work on an extended tikzposter class: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120988/14200 Try fancytikzposter to change your background.

Answer (score 7):

You can try adding something like

```
\node[above right,opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-16x10}};
```

immediately after `\begin{document}`. This relies on the fact that the whole poster is essentially one big `tikzpicture`, and that the class defines a coordinate `bottomleft` in the lower left corner of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{tikzposter} 
\usetheme{Rays}
\title{Something or other}
\author{A Bloke}
\institute{Department of Complete Nonsense\\[0.5cm] \url{bloke@nonsense.edu}}
\usepackage{url,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\node[above right,opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-16x10}};

\maketitle

\block{Stuff}{\lipsum}
\end{document}
```