# tikzposter without maketitle

Tags: tikzposter

I want to skip the `\maketitle` command in tikzposter, since I already have a title box in a separate file (which I include as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121000/adding-a-background-image-with-tikz-poster#309888)).

However, omitting `\maketitle` results in some y-offset for my content (`\block{...}`) at about half of poster height. So I have some huge white space, I want to get rid of.

I also tried to use an empty title by setting `\settitle{}` in the preamble, and then using `\maketitle[linewidth=0]`, but this still gives me an empty title box with a (thin) frame (default theme), which overlaps my actual background image title.

So how do I use tikzposter if I don't need the `\maketitle` command?

minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\settitle{}     % empty title

\begin{document}

% background image with actual title
\node[above right,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};

% insert empty title box
% \maketitle[linewidth=0]

% content
\block{Test}{\lipsum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Does adding `\maketitle` give you what you want? You made it empty by `\settitle{}`.

Comment: @marmot as explained above: no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tikzposter` redefines `\maketitle` which includes (amongst others) setting `\TP@blocktop`, a length which seems to determine the vertical position of the first block.

```
\documentclass[]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\settitle{}     % empty title

\begin{document}

% background image with actual title
\node[above right,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};

\makeatletter
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{.47\textheight}
\makeatother

% content
\block{Test}{\lipsum}

\block{Test}{\lipsum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does work as a quick hack. But I would not consider it a real solution, since you have to come up with the height yourself.

Comment: @Feodoran But how should tex know where you want to have your block? In the original definition it was more or less  `.5\textheight-"height of the title block"`. As you don't have a title I put `.03\textheight` to have a bit of margin at the top.

Comment: Oh, right, the image spans the whole page. Is there maybe a way to pass an image with is inserted instead of the title? Then the image would not need span the whole page.

Comment: @Feodoran Yes, you can find the original definition in `tikzposter.cls` and redefine it accordingly. However I wonder why?

Comment: So the first block will be placed automatically after the title, no matter its height. How do I find the path for `tikzposter.cls` (texlive)?

Comment: @Feodoran Typically the path would be something like `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzposter/tikzposter.cls`