# Why is my tikzposter not aligned at the top of the page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, alignment, tikzposter

Why does Latex insist on centering this table? I can't get it to align the table to the top of the page.  If I add additional table lines, or even other blocks, they are pushed out the bottom of the page.  Please see my MWE below:

```
\documentclass[25pt, landscape]{tikzposter} % font 12, 14, 17, 20 or 25

% -------------------------------------------- This determines the size and margins
\geometry{paperwidth=24in, paperheight=36in}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-1\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-1\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \block{Exciting Table to Wow and Impress my Client}{
  \begin{tabular}{c p{25cm} p{30cm} |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  
 \#  & A thing & Description of the thing & JAN & FEB & MAR & APR & MAY & JUN & JUL & AUG & SEP & OCT & NOV & DEC \\ 

 \hline \hline
 1& One reason to love Latex & Terse and impressive example. & X & & & X& & & X& & &X & &  \\
 2& Several more reasons & So many examples to list! & X & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
  \end{tabular}
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`tikzposter` reserves a space for the title.
If you don't want a title and want reclaim the space, you must nullify it with an appropriate `\definetitlestyle` and later invoke it with  `\maketitle`.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[25pt, landscape]{tikzposter} % font 12, 14, 17, 20 or 25

% -------------------------------------------- This determines the size and margins
\geometry{paperwidth=24in, paperheight=36in}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-1\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-1\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother

\definetitlestyle{Zero}{titletotopverticalspace=-260pt,titletoblockverticalspace=0pt}{} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \usetitlestyle{Zero}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \maketitle% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

    \block{Exciting Table to Wow and Impress my Client}{
        \begin{tabular}{c p{25cm} p{30cm} |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            
            \#  & A thing & Description of the thing & JAN & FEB & MAR & APR & MAY & JUN & JUL & AUG & SEP & OCT & NOV & DEC \\ 
            
            \hline \hline
            1& One reason to love Latex & Terse and impressive example. & X & & & X& & & X& & &X & &  \\
            2& Several more reasons & So many examples to list! & X & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
        \end{tabular}
    }

\end{document}
```

If you decide to have a title everything is easier. The block will be right there.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[25pt, landscape]{tikzposter} % font 12, 14, 17, 20 or 25

% -------------------------------------------- This determines the size and margins
\geometry{paperwidth=24in, paperheight=36in}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-1\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-1\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother

\usetitlestyle{Default}

 \title{A tikzposter}
\author{By myself}
\institute{}

\begin{document}

 \maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=30pt,titletoblockverticalspace=40pt ]% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

    \block{Exciting Table to Wow and Impress my Client}{
        \begin{tabular}{c p{25cm} p{30cm} |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            
            \#  & A thing & Description of the thing & JAN & FEB & MAR & APR & MAY & JUN & JUL & AUG & SEP & OCT & NOV & DEC \\ 
            
            \hline \hline
            1& One reason to love Latex & Terse and impressive example. & X & & & X& & & X& & &X & &  \\
            2& Several more reasons & So many examples to list! & X & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
        \end{tabular}
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413936/tikzposter-without-maketitle