# How to Insert Figures in the Header and Footer?

Tags: posters, figure-placement

In my university, they require us to use this figure in the header of the poster,

[image]

and this one at the bottom.

[image]

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,url}

\title{\LARGE{A note on the generalized maximal numerical range of operators}}
\author{xxxxxxxxx (joint work with xxxxxxxxxx and xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)}
\institute{Faculty of Science and xxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\insertlogoi[2][]{\def\@insertlogoi{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand\insertlogoii[2][]{\def\@insertlogoii{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newlength\LogoSep
\setlength\LogoSep{0pt}

\insertlogoi[width=10cm]{example-image-a}
\insertlogoii[width=10cm]{example-image-b}

\renewcommand\maketitle[1][]{  % #1 keys
    \normalsize
    \setkeys{title}{#1}
    % Title dummy to get title height
    \node[transparent,inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        (TP@title) at ($(0, 0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)$) {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};
    \draw let \p1 = ($(TP@title.north)-(TP@title.south)$) in node {
        \setlength{\TP@titleheight}{\y1}
        \setlength{\titleheight}{\y1}
        \global\TP@titleheight=\TP@titleheight
        \global\titleheight=\titleheight
    };

    % Compute title position
    \setlength{\titleposleft}{-0.5\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titleposright}{\titleposleft+\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titlepostop}{0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace}
    \setlength{\titleposbottom}{\titlepostop-\titleheight}

    % Title style (background)
    \TP@titlestyle

    % Title node
    \node[inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        at (0,0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)
        (title)
        {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=west]
      at ([xshift=-\LogoSep]title.west)
      {\@insertlogoi};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=east]
      at ([xshift=\LogoSep]title.east)
      {\@insertlogoii};

    % Settings for blocks
    \normalsize
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{\titleposbottom-\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

 % Title block with title, author, logo, etc.
\maketitle
 \block{Basic Block}{Text}
 \begin{columns}

 % FIRST column
\column{0.6}% Width set relative to text width

\block{Large Column}{Text\\Text\\Text Text Text}
\note{Note with default behavior}
\note[targetoffsetx=12cm, targetoffsety=-1cm, angle=20, rotate=25]
{Note \\ offset and rotated}

 % First column - second block
\block{Block titles with enough text will automatically obey spacing requirements }
{Text\\Text}

 % First column - third block
\block{Sample Block 4}{T\\E\\S\\T}

 % SECOND column
\column{0.4}
 %Second column with first block's top edge aligned with with previous column's top.

 % Second column - first block
\block[titleleft]{Smaller Column}{Test}

 % Second column - second block
\block[titlewidthscale=0.6, bodywidthscale=0.8]
{Variable width title}{Block with smaller width.}

 % Second column - third block
\block{}{Block with no title}

 % Second column - A collection of blocks in subcolumn environment.
\begin{subcolumns}
    \subcolumn{0.27} \block{1}{First block.} \block{2}{Second block}
    \subcolumn{0.4} \block{Sub-columns}{Sample subblocks\\Second subcolumn}
    \subcolumn{0.33} \block{4}{Fourth} \block{}{Final Subcolumn block}
\end{subcolumns}

 % Bottomblock
\block{Final Block in column}{
    Sample block.
}
\end{columns}
\block[titleleft, titleoffsetx=2em, titleoffsety=1em, bodyoffsetx=2em,%
 bodyoffsety=-2cm, roundedcorners=10, linewidth=0mm, titlewidthscale=0.7,%
 bodywidthscale=0.9, bodyverticalshift=2cm, titleright]
{Block outside of Columns}{Along with several options enabled}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why didn‘t you tag tikzposter? Why did you tag float? You neither have any, nor do you want some, do you? Why didn‘t you specify the theme explicitly?

Comment: For me I just want to write my poster with Latex since many other will write it in Microsoft Word. But I need to keep the same header and footer like the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image in the header can be placed with `\node[below,inner sep=0pt] at (0,{\paperheight/2}) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}};` and similarly for the footer.

Code related to `insertlogo` was removed.

The option `titletotopverticalspace=7cm` is given to the command `\maketitle`.

Note that in the question, there is `\LARGE{<text>}`. It is better to write `{\LARGE <text>}`, as explained for example on [\bfseries bolds more than intended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131180/bfseries-bolds-more-than-intended).

[image]

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,url}

\title{{\LARGE A note on the generalized maximal numerical range of operators}}
\author{xxxxxxxxx (joint work with xxxxxxxxxx and xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)}
\institute{Faculty of Science and xxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}




\begin{document}
\node[below,inner sep=0pt] at (0,{\paperheight/2}) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[above,inner sep=0pt] at (0,{-\paperheight/2}) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-b}};

 % Title block with title, author, logo, etc.
\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=7cm]
 \block{Basic Block}{Text}
 \begin{columns}

 % FIRST column
\column{0.6}% Width set relative to text width

\block{Large Column}{Text\\Text\\Text Text Text}
\note{Note with default behavior}
\note[targetoffsetx=12cm, targetoffsety=-1cm, angle=20, rotate=25]
{Note \\ offset and rotated}

 % First column - second block
\block{Block titles with enough text will automatically obey spacing requirements }
{Text\\Text}

 % First column - third block
\block{Sample Block 4}{T\\E\\S\\T}

 % SECOND column
\column{0.4}
 %Second column with first block's top edge aligned with with previous column's top.

 % Second column - first block
\block[titleleft]{Smaller Column}{Test}

 % Second column - second block
\block[titlewidthscale=0.6, bodywidthscale=0.8]
{Variable width title}{Block with smaller width.}

 % Second column - third block
\block{}{Block with no title}

 % Second column - A collection of blocks in subcolumn environment.
\begin{subcolumns}
    \subcolumn{0.27} \block{1}{First block.} \block{2}{Second block}
    \subcolumn{0.4} \block{Sub-columns}{Sample subblocks\\Second subcolumn}
    \subcolumn{0.33} \block{4}{Fourth} \block{}{Final Subcolumn block}
\end{subcolumns}

 % Bottomblock
\block{Final Block in column}{
    Sample block.
}
\end{columns}
\block[titleleft, titleoffsetx=2em, titleoffsety=1em, bodyoffsetx=2em,%
 bodyoffsety=-2cm, roundedcorners=10, linewidth=0mm, titlewidthscale=0.7,%
 bodywidthscale=0.9, bodyverticalshift=2cm, titleright]
{Block outside of Columns}{Along with several options enabled}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But please I want to delete the block of the title since the title will be written in the figure.

Comment: @Student The block of the title can be removed by removing `\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=7cm]` and replacing it by `\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@blocktop}{.4\textheight}
\makeatother`, as in the answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413939. For reference: this question is also answered with your question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709289/delete-the-block-title.