# delete the block title

Tags: tikzposter

```
    \documentclass{tikzposter}

    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,url}

    \title{{\LARGE A note on the generalized maximal numerical range of operators}}
    \author{xxxxxxxxx (joint work with xxxxxxxxxx and xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)}
    \institute{Faculty of Science and xxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}




    \begin{document}
    \node[below,inner sep=0pt] at (0,{\paperheight/2}) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}};
    \node[above,inner sep=0pt] at (0,{-\paperheight/2}) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-b}};

     % Title block with title, author, logo, etc.
    \maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=7cm]
     \block{Basic Block}{Text}
     \begin{columns}

     % FIRST column
    \column{0.6}% Width set relative to text width

    \block{Large Column}{Text\\Text\\Text Text Text}
    \note{Note with default behavior}
    \note[targetoffsetx=12cm, targetoffsety=-1cm, angle=20, rotate=25]
    {Note \\ offset and rotated}

     % First column - second block
    \block{Block titles with enough text will automatically obey spacing requirements }
    {Text\\Text}

     % First column - third block
    \block{Sample Block 4}{T\\E\\S\\T}

     % SECOND column
    \column{0.4}
     %Second column with first block's top edge aligned with with previous column's top.

     % Second column - first block
    \block[titleleft]{Smaller Column}{Test}

     % Second column - second block
    \block[titlewidthscale=0.6, bodywidthscale=0.8]
    {Variable width title}{Block with smaller width.}

     % Second column - third block
    \block{}{Block with no title}

     % Second column - A collection of blocks in subcolumn environment.
    \begin{subcolumns}
        \subcolumn{0.27} \block{1}{First block.} \block{2}{Second block}
        \subcolumn{0.4} \block{Sub-columns}{Sample subblocks\\Second subcolumn}
        \subcolumn{0.33} \block{4}{Fourth} \block{}{Final Subcolumn block}
    \end{subcolumns}

     % Bottomblock
    \block{Final Block in column}{
        Sample block.
    }
    \end{columns}
    \block[titleleft, titleoffsetx=2em, titleoffsety=1em, bodyoffsetx=2em,%
     bodyoffsety=-2cm, roundedcorners=10, linewidth=0mm, titlewidthscale=0.7,%
     bodywidthscale=0.9, bodyverticalshift=2cm, titleright]
    {Block outside of Columns}{Along with several options enabled}

    \end{document}
```

> I want to delete the block title since the title will be written in the figure in header. I tried to use an empty title by setting `\settitle{}`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the source code corresponding to the `\maketitle` in the `.cls` file and made some minor modifications.

```latex
% \maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=7cm]
\makeatletter
\setkeys{title}{titletotopverticalspace=7cm}
\setlength{\titlepostop}{0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace}
\setlength{\titleposbottom}{\titlepostop-\titleheight}
\setlength{\TP@blocktop}{\titleposbottom-\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}
\makeatother
```

[image]