Tikzposter with image as background
I'm working on creating a poster using LaTeX. The symposium I'm attending provided me with the header and footer templates for the poster. I've successfully set the image as the background, but I'm facing an issue where there's still a white box overlaying the background. I need to remove the top and bottom parts of this white box and place all the poster information within the remaining white area of the background.

I'd tried changing values with no sucess. Hope someone can help me.
.style file : https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/unitartucs-poster-template-portrait/jzksrrsssgrv
Here's my code
\documentclass[20pt,margin=1in,innermargin=.25in,blockverticalspace=.5in]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=23.39in,paperheight= 33.11in} % A1 size
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{unitartu-theme}
\usepackage{background} % For setting background image

% Set visible text area for A1
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{21.39in}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{50.11in}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mwe} % for placeholder images
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{bbm}

% Set theme parameters
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usetheme{UniTartuTheme}
\usecolorstyle{UniTartuStyle}

% Define background image settings
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1, % Adjust this scale as necessary
  color=black, % Background color if no image is used
  opacity=1, % Background opacity
  angle=0, % Rotation of the image
  position=current page.north, % Place at the top of the page
  nodeanchor=north, % Anchor point for positioning
  contents={%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight ]{figures/Slide1.jpg}%
  }, % Path to your background image
  vshift=0, % Adjust vertical position (negative moves the image down)
  hshift=0in % No horizontal shift needed
}


%document part
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\centering
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Section 1}{
       \lipsum[30]

        
     \lipsum[10]
     
     
    \lipsum[20]
}
    \block{Section 2}{
        \lipsum[100]
    }


    \column{0.5}
    \block{Section 3}{
        \lipsum[100]

    }

    \block{Conclusions}{
        \lipsum[100]
        \cite{dirac} \cite{knuthwebsite}
    }
        \block{References}{
                \begin{center}
                   \mbox{}\vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \printbibliography[heading=none] 
        \end{center}
        }

\end{columns}
\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add an screenshot of your result and mark there your issue?

@Mensch I just edit the question with the image. Thank you!

Please share a link to the custom .sty file

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ready! I just edit the question

I solved the problem with this:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413936/tikzposter-without-maketitle

Should we close this as a duplicate, then?
