# Sending tkiz picture to background to be able to draw text on top of image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, formatting

I have achieved the following result:

[image]

With the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, transform shape]
\node [anchor=north, inner sep=0pt]
at (current page.north)
{
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1.01\paperwidth]{images/header1}};

};
    \draw (1, 1) node {Hello world};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that I want the image to have full opacity. But if I do this, since the image is drawn OVER the text, it will disappear. I need the text to be drawn over the image instead.

Comment: Add your background picture _before_ any text...

Comment: Or add background image on `background` layer (see `backgrounds` tikzlibrary)

Comment: You can also use \AddThispageHook{...} (everypage package).

Comment: Is that a `tikzposter`? So you want something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121000/adding-a-background-image-with-tikz-poster/309888#309888?