# difficulty compiling TikZ code - unknown key "breakable"

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, posters, tcolorbox

In attempting to compile some TikZ related code by Gonzalo Medina, I am running into difficulties. The code is accessible here:

[Creation of a new poster template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120898/creation-of-a-new-poster-template/120942#120942)

Specifically, I am encountering the following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/library/breakable' and I a
m going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems,breakable}

?
```

Could you suggest how I might approach this problem?

EDIT: I have added the code I'm using below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30cm,paperheight=45cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems,breakable}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{40,96,139}

\tcbset{
mybox/.style={
  breakable,
  freelance,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  width=\linewidth,
  frame code={%
  \path[draw=black,rounded corners,fill=white,drop shadow]
    (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);
  },
  title code={
  \path[top color=myblue!30,bottom color=myblue!0.5,rounded corners,draw=none]
    ([xshift=\pgflinewidth,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]frame.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]frame.south east|-title.south east);
  \path[fill=myblue]
  ([xshift=5pt,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]frame.north west) to[out=0,in=180] ([xshift=50pt,yshift=-5pt]title.south west) -- ([xshift=-50pt,yshift=-5pt]title.south east) to[out=0,in=180] ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]frame.north east) -- cycle;
  },
  fonttitle=\Large\bfseries\sffamily,
  fontupper=\sffamily,
  fontlower=\sffamily,
  before=\par\medskip\noindent,
  after=\par\medskip,
  center title,
  toptitle=3pt,
  top=11pt,
  colback=white
}}

\newtcolorbox{block}[2][\linewidth]{mybox,width=#1,title=#2}

\makeatletter
\newlength\TitleHt

\newcommand\InsertTitle[1]{\gdef\@InsertTitle{#1}}
\newcommand\InsertAuthor[1]{\gdef\@InsertAuthor{#1}}
\newcommand\InsertInstitute[1]{\gdef\@InsertInstitute{#1}}
\newcommand\InsertEmail[1]{\gdef\@InsertEmail{\url{#1}}}

\newcommand\Titlefont{\color{white}\fontsize{40}{48}\sffamily}
\newcommand\Authorfont{\color{white}\LARGE\sffamily}
\newcommand\Institutefont{\color{white}\Large\sffamily}
\newcommand\Emailfont{\color{white}\normalsize}

\newcommand\MakeTitle{%
\setbox0=\vbox{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth}@{}}
 \Titlefont\@InsertTitle \\
 \Authorfont\@InsertAuthor \\
 \Institutefont\@InsertInstitute \\
 \Emailfont\@InsertEmail \\
\end{tabular}}%
\setlength\TitleHt{\ht0}%
\addtolength\TitleHt{\dp0}%
\addtolength\TitleHt{1.5cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path[clip] 
  (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east) --
  ([yshift=-0.5\TitleHt]current page.north east) to[out=270,in=0] 
  ([yshift=-\TitleHt,xshift=-60pt]current page.north east) -- 
  ([yshift=-\TitleHt,xshift=60pt]current page.north west) to[out=180,in=270]
  ([yshift=-0.5\TitleHt]current page.north west) -- cycle;
\fill[fill=myblue] 
  (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east) --
  ([yshift=-0.5\TitleHt]current page.north east) to[out=270,in=0] 
  ([yshift=-\TitleHt,xshift=-60pt]current page.north east) -- 
  ([yshift=-\TitleHt,xshift=60pt]current page.north west) to[out=180,in=270]
  ([yshift=-0.5\TitleHt]current page.north west) -- cycle;
\path[top color=myblue!15,bottom color=myblue!65] 
  (current page.north east) .. controls
    ([yshift=-0.2\TitleHt,xshift=-50pt]current page.north east) 
    and ([yshift=-0.7\TitleHt,xshift=0pt]current page.north east) ..
  ([yshift=-1.1\TitleHt,xshift=-90pt]current page.north east)  .. controls
    ([yshift=-0.8\TitleHt,xshift=5pt]current page.north east) 
    and ([yshift=-0.2\TitleHt,xshift=-22pt]current page.north east) ..
  (current page.north east);
\path[top color=myblue!15,bottom color=myblue!65] 
  (current page.north east) .. controls
    ([yshift=-0.2\TitleHt,xshift=-90pt]current page.north east) 
    and ([yshift=-0.7\TitleHt,xshift=-20pt]current page.north east) ..
  ([yshift=-1.1\TitleHt,xshift=-110pt]current page.north east)  .. controls
    ([yshift=-0.8\TitleHt,xshift=-15pt]current page.north east) 
    and ([yshift=-0.2\TitleHt,xshift=-62pt]current page.north east) ..
  (current page.north east);
\node[anchor=south,text width=\paperwidth,align=center] at ([yshift=\the\dimexpr-\TitleHt+0.25cm\relax]current page.north) {\box0};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\InsertTitle{The Title of the Presentation}
\InsertAuthor{The Author}
\InsertInstitute{The Name of the Institution}
\InsertEmail{www.stackexchange.com}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{myblue!30}
\MakeTitle
\vspace*{2cm}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{block}{Title of a block}
\lipsum[2]
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Title of a block}
\lipsum[3]
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Title of a block}
\lipsum[2]
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Title of a block}
\lipsum[4]
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Title of a block}
\lipsum[2]
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Title of a block}
\lipsum[3]
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Title of a block}
\lipsum[4]
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Title of a block}
\lipsum[1]
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Title of a block}
\lipsum[5]
\end{block}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you include `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`? If yes, then probably you need to update your TeX distro for the newest versions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I do indeed have tcolorbox included and I have updated TeX Live to the latest version. Unfortunately, I am still encountering the same problem. I've added the code I'm using to the original post.

Comment: I can confirm that your code compiles with no problems for me using TL2013.  Add `\listfiles` at the start of your document and then cut-and-paste the resulting list into your question.  (It might help to prune the package list before doing this, I don't believe that *all* those packages are needed to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: I also can confirm that the code compiles with MikTeX on my maschine with no problems. A thinkable problem could be a 'half-installed' tcolorbox package (if installed manually). Be sure that `tcolorbox.sty` and ALL `*.code.tex` files with identical version numbers are installed. Starting from version 2.31 the packages makes an automated check for the correct library versions. By the way: I think for this application you do not need 'breakable' at all (?).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which can't be reproduced by others (see comments).

Comment: (I had a similar problem but it was because I was missing `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}`.)