# Breakable boxes with Tikz and right and leftmargin

Tags: mdframed, tikz-styles, polyglossia

I've found a method to obtain breakable boxes, using polyglossia for arabic, and the Tikz package and I have two problems...

1) the commands leftmargin and rightmargin of Tikz have no effect on the boxes... there's a package deciding for the width of the box... which one and how could I remain it ?

2) I want to add a title for some frames (different for every frame) in the box of the frametitle (here Example). How can I declare such environment ?

Thank you for help

Here's a simple example with my packages (don't worry for the text written right to left !!)

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}%{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{slashbox} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{minitoc} 

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{fmultico}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}



\tikzstyle{titleframe} =
    [draw=black, thick, scale=.7, fill=white,% 
        line width=0.1pt, text=black, rectangle,  
        left, minimum height=.5cm]


\newcounter{example}
\renewcommand*\theexample{Example~\arabic{section}.\arabic{example}}


\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{examplestyle}{%
    outerlinewidth=1em,%
    outerlinecolor=white,%
    leftmargin=-1em,%
    rightmargin=-1em,%
    middlelinewidth=1.2pt,%
%    roundcorner=5pt,%
    linecolor=gray!20,%
    backgroundcolor=white,%
    innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
%    skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
    skipabove={\dimexpr1\baselineskip\relax},
    skipbelow={0em},
    needspace=3\baselineskip,
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
    settings={\global\stepcounter{example}},
    firstextra={%
            \node[titleframe,xshift=-1cm] at (P-|P) %
                    {\RL{~{\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexample}}~}};},%
    singleextra={%
%        \node[titleframe,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
         \node[titleframe,xshift=-1cm] at (P-|P) %
            {~{\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexample}}~};}
}
\makeatother



\newenvironment{example}%
{\begin{mdframed}[style=examplestyle]}{\end{mdframed}}


\begin{document}

    \begin{example}
    To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
    equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
    For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}

   \end{example}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tcolorbox`. There is still room for improvement but this should serve as a starting point.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}%{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{slashbox}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{fmultico}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}


\newcounter{example}
\renewcommand*\theexample{Example~\arabic{section}.\arabic{example}}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=example]{example}[3][]{%
enhanced,
colback=blue!10!white,
colframe=orange,
top=6mm,
enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,
enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,
fontupper=\normalsize,
label={#3},
overlay unbroken and first={%
\node[rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black,fill=blue!20!white,
inner sep=1mm,anchor=east,font=\small,text width=0.5\textwidth]
at ([xshift=-1cm]frame.north east)
{\strut\RL{\textbf{Example \thetcbcounter: #2}}};},
breakable,
width=0.9\textwidth,       %%% change the width here.
#1}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{example}{My title goes long and long and long}{ex:first}   %% last one is label
    To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
    equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
    For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}

   \end{example}

   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you, it seems good. I think that there was a problem of compatibility between tcolorbox and polyglossia, and it seems that it isn't now. I see this in detail today and tell you about it. Many thanks

Comment: Hello Harish. After updating the package options of tcolorbox (most), and copy-paste ...exactly... your doc, I got the title frame "Example 1..." written justified on the left not on the right... How can I paste the pdf file here ??

Comment: Hello I solved this last problem... It's the option "text width=0.5\textwidth".. when you bring it, it justifies the text on the right... What's the effect of this option ?.. I'll read the doc of the package... Thanks

Comment: Hello Harish. Everything is going well this macro, else that when the box is too long, it breaks pages "without any logic"... it puts a blank page before the long box... sometimes inside the box... What's do you think the problem ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Difficult to say without code. May be you can ask a new question...

Comment: I've just seen your answer. Ok Harish Thank you. I hope that the number of characters is allowed here...