# how to add list of collaboration in the title block of fancytikzposter?

Tags: tikzposter

I am preparing my poster for the first time using Latex. I found the tikZ poster sources made by [Elena Botoeva](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120898/creation-of-a-new-poster-template), very easy, quick and beautiful. Since my Latex knowledge is poor, I do not know how to make some simple changes in the original source code.

**My Goal:**

I would like to replace the section of "Institute" which is right after the author name and instead use there "Representing the collaboration of:" and then put two more text column where I can put list of all the institute. For example see my old poster [here](http://www.ips.if.uj.edu.pl/files/4061d6e5b2752d5556960e6b74aa96e1/khatri-parol%20poster%20EuNPC2012.pdf).

**Edit:**
Thanks for the reply to my question. I made a little search and managed to do multicolumn in the section "\institute" as following:

```
    \institute{
    \begin{multicols}{2}[\textbf{Representing the collaboration of:}]
    Institute 1 \\
    Institute 2 \\
    Institute 3\\ 
    \columnbreak
    Institute 4\\
    Institute 5\\
    Institute 6
    \end{multicols}
    }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer of `fancytikzposter` has joined efforts with some other collaborators and they have created the [`tikzposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter) class. You can use some `minipage`s inside the `\institute` field to provide the information with the desired formatting:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\title{The Title}
\institute{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
  \itshape\small representing the collaboration of
  \end{center}
  \begin{minipage}{.40\linewidth}
  \raggedright
  Institute of Mathematics \\
  Institute of Mathematics \\
  Institute of Mathematics
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.40\linewidth}
  \raggedright
  Institute of Physics \\
  Institute of Physics \\
  Institute of Physics
  \end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}%
}
\author{The Author A and The Author B}
\titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
\column{0.7}
\block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
\note{Notetext}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]