# Logo next title poster

Tags: floats, positioning, posters

I have a problem with placing one logo on the appropriate place in my poster. I have two logo's, there is no problem with the first logo, which stands left to the title. The second logo is right to the title, but it should be translated to the left. The situation now is that the right logo leaves the box of my poster.

The scale is fine etc, I only need to shift it to the left (there is enough place, the title is not too big). Here is the latex command for the "title box" of my poster.

```
  \begin{document}
  % Left logo
  \begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][c]{0.12\textwidth}
  %\hfill
  \hspace*{1.2cm}
  \includegraphics[height=3cm,angle=0]{logo1.eps}
  \end{minipage}
  %Title
  \begin{minipage}[c][0.05\textheight][c]{0.75\textwidth}
  \begin{center} \LARGE
  {\textbf{Title}}\\[-5.0mm]
  {\large \textbf{Name 1}$^{(1)}$, \textbf{Name 2}$^{(2)}$}\\[3mm] \small
  {$^{(1)}$ department, University, country \\[2mm]
  $^{(2)}$ department, University, country \\[2mm]
   contact: \emph{email}}
  \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  % Right logo
  \begin{minipage}[c][10cm][c]{5cm}
  \begin{figure}[H]
  \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=13cm]{logo2.eps}
  \end{figure}
  \end{minipage}

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your have scaled your second logo to width `13cm` but placed it in a `minipage` of width `5cm`. When you write

```
 \begin{minipage}[c][10cm][c]{5cm}
   ...
 \end{minipage}
```

you are producing a box that is `10cm` high and `5cm` wide, with material centered horizontally and vertically.  You need to make the width at least as large as your image:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\begin{document}
% Left logo
\begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][c]{0.12\textwidth}
  % \hfill
  \hspace*{1.2cm}
  \includegraphics[height=3cm,angle=0]{example-image-a.png}
\end{minipage}
% Title
\begin{minipage}[c][0.05\textheight][c]{0.75\textwidth}
  \begin{center} \LARGE
    {\textbf{Title}}\\[-5.0mm]
    {\large \textbf{Name 1}$^{(1)}$, \textbf{Name 2}$^{(2)}$}\\[3mm] \small
    {$^{(1)}$ department, University, country \\[2mm]
    $^{(2)}$ department, University, country \\[2mm]
    contact: \emph{email}}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}
% Right logo
\begin{minipage}[c][10cm][c]{15cm}
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=13cm]{example-image-b.png}
  \end{figure}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Your code didn't show which poster class you were using, see [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341/15925) for a nubber of choices.

You must make sure there is enough space for your final logo.  As it stands the left logo plus the heading block fill `0.12+0.75=0.87` of the `\textwidth`. Thus final logo must have width less than `0.13\textwidth` to fit on the page.  In the above example this ensured by using `a0` paper, as provided by the `a0poster` package.

Comment: Thank you! Your first parapgraph does the job for me. I thought the first coordinate was width and the second height.