# Add Logo to LaTeX poster

Tags: graphics, positioning, beamerposter

I'm using [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster) template to create a poster. I would like to add a logo to the top right corner of the poster, next to the tittle of the poster.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136515/logo-next-title-poster

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to add this after your `\begin{document}`:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{} 
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\node [shift={(-10 cm,-5cm)}] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=5cm]{logo}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
}
```

I had to compile twice.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `tikz` package to accomplish this easily. Working with the template you mentioned, you have to include:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

in the preamble. Then, in the body of your document (right after `\begin{document}`) add the following:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{} 
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
     \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=3cm]  at (current page.north east)
     {\includegraphics[height=5cm]{logo}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
```

which yields the following output (zoomed-in to the top right corner):

[image]

You then can of course adjust the dimensions of the logo by specifying different values in the square brackets right after the `\includegraphics` command.

Lastly, `inner sep` specifies de diagonal distance to the top right corner.

Hope it helps!