# Tex template for "Call for Papers"

Tags: templates, flyers

I need to prepare a 'Call for Papers' document for an academic conference. Is there any LaTeX template or TeX examples which can help me prepare a Call for Papers doc easily?

I am looking to make a conference brochure like in [this link](http://www.ieee-icc.org/2014/ICC2014_CFP%20%281%29.pdf).

Comment: None that I'm aware of.  But it wouldn't be hard to design as long as you think of what elements you(r discipline) need(s) before you sit down to code it.  Are keynote speakers already decided?  Do you need an image?  Are suggested topics going to be given? Does the page need some special decoration around the borders?  How many 'levels' of text will be needed?  How should the contact information be configured?  And so forth.

Comment: @jon: I am looking to make a conference brochure like in [this link](http://www.ieee-icc.org/2014/ICC2014_CFP%20(1).pdf).

Comment: Hmm, I don't see much advantage to doing something like that in LaTeX.  There is definitely no class that gets you most of the way there by default.  What it involves is finding a lot of graphics, packages like `tcolorbox` and `multicol` and one or two 'sans' fonts that can be scaled to different sizes (for which I'd be inclined to use `fontspec`).  Also something that can put 'watermarks' on the page (or PGF/TikZ).  It is a good example of how separating form and content will be crucial for keeping design consistency across all the different sizing, bolding, and colouring.

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but you can try with some [`poster package/class`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex/609#609)