# LaTeX Poster for a Beginner

Tags: posters

I'm very new to LaTeX and I need to create a conference-style poster for a module i'm currently doing. I've been looking around trying to find out how I should best apporaoch this but I can't really find anything concise. I was wondering if anyone would be able to gudie me in how I can approach making an a0 poster in LaTeX?

I've read that I could use the a0poster document class but then i've also seen alot about beamerposter, this doesn't need to be a massively complex poster but I would like it to look nice and professional as it's going to count for 20% of my grade. I'm using MiKTeX and Texmaker. Any help or advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you seen [How to create posters using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341)

Comment: My mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a good poster template: http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/ (scroll down a bit to see some examples).

Comment: have a look at these answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex/7309#7309