# How do I generate a title in beamerposter?

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I am trying to generate a title for my poster using `beamerposter` and it seems to be unnecessarily difficult.

In the following example code, the usage of `maketitle` causes a full-page title, while I am just looking for something towards the top and center-aligned.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
  \mode<presentation>
  {
 \usetheme{default}
}
  \usepackage{type1cm}
  \usepackage{calc} 
  \usepackage{times}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  \boldmath
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=101.6,height=76.2,scale=1,debug]{beamerposter}
  \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
  \title{My Awesome Paper Title}
  \author{Merlin2011}
  \institute{FooBar University}
  \date{June 6, 2014}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \maketitle
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I generate a simple title for my poster without eating up the whole page?

Comment: It is strange to make a poster using beamer since you will not create more than one frame.

Comment: @Sigur, The `beamerposter` package was recommended [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342/24402) and I am trying to learn how to use it.

Comment: @Sigur I've used `beamerposter` for a few posters so far; it seems to work well for the task. When you think about it, it's the same idea most Office users go for—a Powerpoint with only one gigantic slide.

Comment: If you look at `example.tex` it uses several `block` environments in a single `frame` with `columns`. It specifies `\title` but does not use `\maketitle`. I would try basing your own poster on the sample poster and see if that works better since the example basically seems to be the documentation.

Comment: If you are still starting, may be you want to consider [tikzposter](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzposter). It's documented and uses `maketitle`. Some examples [in this file](https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/downloads/themes.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt. Remove thr `block` environment if you don't want it. Note the skills mentioned in the comment provided by @cfr are the commomly seen skills since a poster is usually over sized and those approaches will be easy to design the layout and debugging.

**Update:** This update includes the `columns` and `column` environments. A total of 3 columns was demonstrated here. `Left column` and `R column` (which has R1 and R2 columns) and thus `0.28\paperwidth`, which is adjustable, is used. Often time, the `begin` and `end column(s)` are the main sources of errors when working on beamerposter IMHO.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
  \mode<presentation>
  {
 \usetheme{default}
}
  \usepackage{type1cm}
  \usepackage{calc} 
  \usepackage{times,lipsum}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  \boldmath
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=101.6,height=76.2,scale=1,debug]{beamerposter}
  \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0.6cm}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=0.6cm}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}     
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!20,top=yellow!30]

%  Title, date and authors of the poster 
\title{My Awesome Paper Title}
\author{Merlin2011}
\institute{FooBar University}
\date{June 6, 2014}
%==the poster content
\begin{document}      %--the poster is one beamer frame, so we have to start with:
\begin{frame}[t]      %--to separate the poster in columns we can use the columns environment
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blue,bg=orange!70}%frame color
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=orange!30}%body color
\begin{block}
{\centering \Huge {My Awesome Paper Title}}
\begin{center}
\Large{
Merlin2011 \\
FooBar University\\
\today}
\end{center}
\end{block}
\begin{columns}                    % outermost column wrapping all columns
\begin{column}{0.28\paperwidth}    % first Left column
Left column ----
\lipsum[2]
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.6\paperwidth}     % 2nd big R column that contains two R1 and R2 columns
\begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=0.6\paperwidth]
\begin{column}{0.28\paperwidth}    % R1 column
R1 column ----
\lipsum[2]
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.28\paperwidth}    % R2 column
R2 column ---
\lipsum[2]
\end{column}
\end{columns}                      % end of 2nd big R column
\end{column}
\end{columns}                      % outermost column wrapping all columns
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
  \mode<presentation>
  {
 \usetheme{default}
}
  \usepackage{type1cm}
  \usepackage{calc} 
  \usepackage{times}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  \boldmath
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=101.6,height=76.2,scale=1,debug]{beamerposter}
  \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0.6cm}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=0.6cm}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}     
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!20,top=yellow!30]

%  Title, date and authors of the poster 
\title{My Awesome Paper Title}
\author{Merlin2011}
\institute{FooBar University}
\date{June 6, 2014}
%==the poster content
\begin{document}      %--the poster is one beamer frame, so we have to start with:
\begin{frame}[t]      %--to separate the poster in columns we can use the columns environment
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blue,bg=orange!70} %frame color
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=orange!30} %body color
\begin{block}         % <----
{\centering \Huge {My Awesome Paper Title}}
\begin{center}
%\Huge {My Awesome Paper Title}\\ 
\Large{
Merlin2011 \\
FooBar University\\
\today}
\end{center}
\end{block}           % <---

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm new to latex, but it looks like you write the title contents twice, both in the `\title{..}` and later, creating a block that contains stuff you've formatted to look like the title? What do you use the `\title{..}` (and `\author{..}` etc) for?

Comment: Oh, the first set is to show on the outer frame at the bottom  (ie., beamer default, a total of 3 section in blue, hard to see though). The second set is on the top for the title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the title area as the headline of a frame.  If you look at the examples here https://github.com/deselaers/latex-beamerposter, you'll find that each complete example includes a custom .sty file, in which the headline template is defined.  This seems to be the way to do it.

Comment: Maybe adding one of the examples would be more helpful.