# Poster lay-out congress poster

Tags: beamerposter, posters

I was wondering if it was possible to make a poster with the following lay-out (this was made in Microsoft Office PowerPoint, but I've had a hard time with images and dragging everything everywhere so I'd like to make it in LaTeX).

Could anyone help me in any way to do this? Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

I have heard of a beamer, but I have no clue on how to make the yellow frame and the blue frame around the text in the blocks.

EDIT:

I managed to do something with mdframed and put it like this in the beamer style:

```
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{\vskip.75ex\begin{beamercolorbox}ht=5ex,dp=0.5ex,center,leftskip=-1em,colsep*=.75ex]{block title}%\usebeamerfont*{block title}%{\phantom{Gg}\Large\insertblocktitle}\end{beamercolorbox}{\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}\usebeamerfont{block body}\begin{mdframed}linewidth=1.7mm,linecolor=ugentblauw,leftmargin=-.30cm,rightmargin=+.58cm,skipabove=-60cm]\begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,colsep*=.75ex,sep=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}   \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}}\setbeamertemplate{block end}{\end{beamercolorbox}\end{mdframed}}
```

Yet, this gives me the following result:
[image]

Leaving ugly and very thin lines at the left. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Go to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex and read about the different options in LaTeX with examples.

Comment: Please review edited post.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like the baposter class (  http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/ ) . It's somewhat limited and I usually end up hacking horribly, but boxes like that are precisely in the scope of that class