# What are advantages & disadvantages of the available poster classes?

Tags: beamerposter, posters, baposter

I've used `baposter` for all my conference posters so far and I am rather happy with it. I tried `beamerposter` before but thought of it being a little less comfortable than `baposter`.

What is your experience with various poster classes?

Comment: The comments of a [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342/153291) has some discussion of `beamerposter`. While the page does not specifically address `beamerposter`, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269296/comparison-umbcposter-vs-baposter-vs-tikzposter) compares various poster classes.