# Multiphase poster

Tags: beamer

A couple of days ago, a friend of mine gave me a template for a poster presentation and it had `\documentclass{multiphaseposter}` in the preamble. Now when I run it, it says `multiphaseposter.cls` not found. I tried searching on the internet for that file extension but it seems it no longer exists. Am I searching in the wrong places or does that type of class for a poster cease to exist?

Comment: It's not in CTAN. Wouldn't it be faster to ask your friend for the `.cls` file?

Comment: I suspect that this is a typo or that you friend created his own class file for the poster.  So contact your friend for additional information and possibly the class file. .

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the friend is probably the only person who is able to answer this question.