# Beamerposter Example

Tags: beamerposter, examples

To help them get started on their own presentations, I'd like to give my students the tex file for an attractive poster presentation using the beamerposter package. Unfortunately, the example that comes with the package is very sparse and doesn't give any sense of what a good poster should look like. I've searched elsewhere and come up empty handed.

Can anyone share the tex file for a complete working example of poster presentation using beamerposter? Preferably, the poster would be the standard (?) 48" x 36" landscape layout.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Very helpful. Thank you. This would make a fine answer; the fact that the tex is available is not obvious in the answer you reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a discussion on this [Stack Exchange Discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex) and then here is a working example [Poster Template referenced in the previous discussion](http://latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster). It is the one I would reference to my students. 
Note: You do not have to have an account with `latextemplates` to download the *.tex file and all supporting files.

I would suggest that you download all the files including the pdf to your computer.  Then rename the pdf so that on subsequent compiles it will not be overwritten.

Then, without changing the downloaded example in any way, compile it and verify that you get the exact same pdf output.

Finally copy all of these file to an archive directory, so that if you make a change which causes serious problems, then you still have the original files to compare to.

Last, a bit of advice on using BeamerPoster.  Because it is creating a large single slide, it is very easy to make an error and not be able to get it to compile.  So, only make changes in a single area for the poster and then recompile.

Also, I strongly recommend that you read the manuals for beamerposter, beamer, and tikz, because there many available options.  p.s. Use www.texdoc.org to quickly obtain the manuals.

Comment: Warning: At the 2016 Joint Mathematics Meetings, I would estimate at least 20% of the student posters used (essentially unmodified) the template linked in this answer. If it is important to you that your poster be unique, you may want to spend more time customizing or look for a more obscure template. (That said, my student was very happy with the way his looked, having spent just a little time changing some colors and a bit of layout. Thank you for the very helpful answer.)