# Why does Overleaf compile the Jacobs Landscape Poster template incorrectly?

Tags: margins, compiling, templates, overleaf, beamerposter

I want to use the [Jacobs Landscape Poster](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster) template to create a poster using `beamerposter`. I am able to successfully compile this template [using Travis CI](https://github.com/samestep/jacobs-landscape-poster); as you can see, the only difference between [the given preview](https://github.com/samestep/jacobs-landscape-poster/blob/1d795ad0fcebc018624b482500f86d02f2d4af4a/conference_poster_1.pdf) and [my compiled output](https://github.com/samestep/jacobs-landscape-poster/blob/1d795ad0fcebc018624b482500f86d02f2d4af4a/main.pdf) is a slight horizontal shift in Table 1.

However, since my Travis CI build takes almost six minutes (which could possibly be reduced, but that's besides the point), I would like to use some other compilation strategy while I'm still editing the poster. When I [import](https://www.overleaf.com/read/gdmhsftfqppb) the template into Overleaf, it compiles with a noticeably larger top margin, which results in equation (3) being cut off at the bottom. Overleaf also changes the fonts in the captions for Figure 2 and Table 1.

I don't usually use Overleaf anyway so normally I would ignore this and just compile on my own machine, but surprisingly, that makes this problem even worse. Using my Ubuntu 18.04.2 setup, I get the undesirable Overleaf output, plus lack of spacing after the colon in figure and table captions, and smaller `itemize` bullets.

---

Here are images of

- the given preview PDF,
- the Travis-generated PDF,
- the Overleaf-generated PDF, and
- my locally-built PDF,

in order:

[image: preview]
[image: Travis CI]
[image: Overleaf]
[image: local]

**How can I properly compile the Jacobs Landscape Poster template without using Travis CI?**

Comment: Exactly which latex installation does your Travis use? And which version? Remember that overleaf is still using texlive 2016

Comment: @daleif From [the log](https://travis-ci.com/samestep/jacobs-landscape-poster/jobs/219739454#L1256): `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`

Comment: Also @daleif according to Overleaf: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.7.12)` and according to my laptop: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`

Comment: 2017 then, still a lot behind. You can only compare compilations from the same larex installation and package versions. A bug may have been fixed in a later version

Comment: @daleif But Travis CI is on 2015 which is even older; thus this is a different issue, correct?

Comment: Perhaps, I haven't checked (we generally does not like going of site for resources as they may disappear the future thus making your example unusable for others).

Comment: BTW why are you using Travis in the first place? Why not install the latest texlive 8n your own pc.

Comment: @daleif I have the most up-to-date TeX Live available from apt on Ubuntu 18.04.2 as far as I can tell. But the issue seems to be that the newer version is giving incorrect behavior compared to the older version which Travis uses.

Comment: @daleif I just upgraded to tl2019 from [here](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2018) but the issue persists.

Comment: Isn't that texlive 2018? As I said, again please make a self contained example others can copy and test as is.

Comment: @daleif My log says `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.7.25)`. I'm not sure what further details you want me to add... the template I linked at the beginning of my post _is_ self-contained and is fairly standard; see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280874/134440). My question is about discrepancies I'm seeing while trying to compile that example, and I've provided exact details on my methods.

Comment: As I said, your question is not usable in the future if the mwe etc is away from this site. So a lot of people will pass in a question like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96624/discussion-between-sam-estep-and-daleif).

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) As others have noted, packages have changed and caused a change to the output in this template. If you really want to determine exactly what's changed, add `\listfiles` to your preamble and compare the output in the .log file of Travis to that of Overleaf. (The file list is printed near the end of the .log file.) But if you don't really care about why it's different and just want it to work on Overleaf, please write us at support@overleaf.com. We can manually adjust your project's TeX Live to match Travis, but this is better done through our support channel.

Comment: @PaulGessler OK, thank you! If I can't figure out how to get my local setup working satisfactorily than I'll probably take you up on that offer. Also, thanks for pointing me to the `\listfiles` command!