# Poster with specific size

Tags: posters

I want to make a poster with size 6 ft. X 3 ft size. 
What kind of document class I should use for this?

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0papper, portrait]{tikzposter} 
\special{papersize=72in,36in} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{pgf,color}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{comment}   
\usetheme{Board}

\title{} 
\author{} 
\date{\today} 
\institute{}
```

Comment: You could try looking at the `beamer` class with the `beamerposter` package. Take a look at the community wiki: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex

Comment: My main concern is 6 ft. X 3 ft. \setlength{\paperwidth}{36in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{72in} are making bottom portion white. How can I adjust size?