# How to create technical conference posters using LaTeX in 2018?

Tags: beamerposter, posters, tikzposter

What do you use create technical posters in 2018?

I tried searching on the web and https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Posters seems to be leaning towards tikzposter for the ease of flexibility.

I have seen [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341/18587) too and the top answer recommends beamerposter but that answer is quite old and dates back to 2010.

This is why I am asking a new question to know what do you use to create technical conference posters in 2018?

Comment: This really depends on the layout you want to achieve. Sometimes I use pure TikZ, sometimes the tcolorbox poster library which is quite powerful. But this question sounds quite broad or opinion-based.

Comment: You can create nice posters with each of the methods: beamer/tikz/tcolorbox/... I think the decision boils down to what syntax you like. If you like beamer syntax, use beamer, if you like tikz, use tikz ....

Comment: @TeXnician Could you please point me to an example of your or another poster done with pure TikZ? It will help me to get started with creating posters in TikZ.

Comment: I do not have one at hand, but really that is all about making a full-page tikzpicture.