# Please provide an example of a poster created in pure TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, posters

Can you provide a very simple but complete example of a poster created in pure TikZ?

This question is inspired by the first comment to "[How to create technical conference posters using LaTeX in 2018?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449435/how-to-create-technical-conference-posters-using-latex-in-2018)"

I like TikZ for drawing diagrams. I am familiar with its syntax.

So if you can provide a minimal example of a poster (say a few columns of text) done with TikZ, it will help me to get started with poster designing with TikZ.

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TikZ gives you infinite options to create your paper, just place all elements where you want them to be.

For example if you want columns, just place nodes wherever you want your columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\path (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\node[draw,align=center,rectangle,yshift=-0.05\paperheight, text width=\textwidth] at (current page.north) {\Huge title};
\node[text width=.3\paperwidth] at (.1\paperwidth,-.1\paperheight) {\lipsum[2]};
\node[text width=.3\paperwidth] at (.5\paperwidth,-.1\paperheight) {\lipsum[2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]