# Openly licensed (La)TeX templates using openly licensed (La)TeX package for conference posters?

Tags: templates, posters, licensing

I don't do posters very much, so I would like to use some existing templates. On the other hand, I want my workflows to be available for reuse, so whatever I use needs to be compatible with that.

To this end, I am looking for cases where both the package and the template for a decent poster are available under an open license (i.e. with no restrictions on the kinds of reuse). Ideally, there would be examples where that template has been used to create posters for scholarly conferences, and the poster's content were openly licensed too, but I can fill that gap.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Classical case of template confusion. You don't need any template.

Comment: @Johannes_B I know I can start using the packages right away (and I have played around with several of them), but if someone else has already thought about poster design things like fonts, color palette or space use and built this into a template, then it would be easier for others to just reuse and modify that, rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: It is not easier to reuse and modify in almost all of cases. LaTeX templates are not what you think.

Answer (score 2):

See for example https://www.latextemplates.com/cat/conference-posters. I have used the Jacobs template myself (in portrait mode). All templates on that site are licensed under CC Attribution-NC-SA.

See also [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex), for example `tikzposter` is on CTAN and licensed under the [LPPL](https://ctan.org/license/lppl1.2), a LaTeX-specific attribution license. Or `beamerposter`, also on CTAN and multi-licensed as both LPPL and GPL.

Furthermore there are examples on https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/poster, with various licenses but several are CC-BY 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I was not aware of that Overleaf gallery, so special thanks for this pointer! I had seen the examples at latextemplates.com , but -NC-licenses impose restrictions on the kinds of reuse (which is why they can't be used on Wikimedia platforms, for example, and why I included this criterion into the OP) and are thus not open. I had also seen the How to create posters thread and tested both packages, just have not seen open templates based on them.