# Why includegraphics within textpos does not appear on PDF

Tags: pdftex

I have a poster in which I need to place several logos in pdf format. For this I use the textpos package together with includegraphics. Why do these logos disappear on the pdf file after the tex is pdflatexed?

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, A4paper,final,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\myrule{$\;$\rule{1.362cm}{.4pt}}
\newcommand{\qrule}{\gray~\rule{3.129362cm}{.4pt}}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\ncircled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
  \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1.93812pt, color=blue] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage[left=1.48075cm,top=2.019012473cm,right=2.1919cm,bottom=2.185391469cm,bindingoffset=0.05cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\huge 

\begin{center}
\scalebox{.672597892}{\bf Vietnam Mathematical Competition}
 \end{center}


\begin{textblock}{20.5}(10.2, 1.)
    \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{pdflogo}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I replace your `pdflogo` whith `example-image` the images appears in the output. Apart fom that: Are you sure that the `article` documentclass is a good choice for producing a poster? Why not use one of the documentclasses specially dedicated to produce posters that are listed here: [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341/134144)

Comment: Also, it should be 'a4paper', not 'A4paper'.

Comment: Further to the comment by @leandriis, my guess would be that there is white space around the logo. You might need to crop it.

Comment: I can view all the logos in the internal viewer of Texstudio. But I can not view the logos when open the pdf file using external pdf adobe.

Comment: Can you make the files available for download and add a link here?

Comment: Yes, the google drive below has one of the pdf logos

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10M6RdKKmW8Oc4utX1DnDrECzridIkK-2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with position and scale that seem to be pushing the image off the page

in addition to setting

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,final,leqno]{article}
```

I also substituted

```
\begin{textblock}{20.5}(10.2, 1.)
    \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{pdflogo}
```

with the following, they may not be ideal values but they fit better

```
\begin{textblock}{10.5}(1.2, 1.)
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{pdflogo}
```

This pulls the image left and into view,
I cant test in adobe but I can see the image mid page in other viewers

[image]