# Table with 3 columns but every cell has its individual height

Tags: tables

Basically I would like to create such a table, where there are 3 columns but every column is just filled up with cells of individual height. So it is not a real grid anymore. The cells are just vertically but not horizontally aligned. I already tried to find an answer to this online but so far I could not find anything. A link to an article or something would already help a lot. Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: Probably easies using some kind of poster setup, see for example the poster setup provised by `tcolorbox`

Comment: That picture looks more like some sort of beamer poster, rather than a table (see the pictures [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342/108704)). Is that what you  really want?

Comment: Maybe the `flowfram` package might help for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with a real table, however, you could use a page with multiple columns and fill them with boxes to achieve this result, see `\multicol` and `\fbox` as a workaround.

Comment: I just realised that i can simply put everything into a table with 3 columns and one row. This also works out. Why did I not see this from the beginning on